# Logical steps to manipulating matrix with SQL

Tags: sql

I have a data table whereby individuals are assigned to any number of roles  as well as any number of Property codes .  All of this information comes to me in 1 table (first table in the image).

Ultimately I'm trying to manipulate the data in such a way that the resulting table expresses the logic illustrated in the bottom screenshot.

Is this going to be possible via SQL or should I seek another solution?

I assume any solution would involve multiple joins?

Table 1, 2, 3
[image]

Optimal resultant table:
[image]

Comment: When you add a role or a property code to table 2 or table 3, it seems like you must then add new columns to table 1 to accommodate those new records.  Wouldn't it be more efficient to remove the columns for roles and properties from table 1 and instead create join tables so that you can link the users in table 1 to the roles and properties in tables 2 & 3?  Then writing queries would be much easier.  If you're using SQL Server, you can use the `pivot` feature to generate your `optimal results`, and recreated your old table 1 too...  Join tables just seem like a much more scalable design.

Comment: The data comes to me in 1 table, (table 1).  I created tables 2 & 3 just to illustrate what the column headers represent, and also because I thought maybe they could be used to facilitate some sort of join.  The data (column headers) is actually completely static except for the Full Name (these are all test names and will later be replaced with e-mail addresses).  Ultimately I'm trying to create something that will be used as a guide for creating a distribution list.